# Concatenate count and non grouping attribute in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have below data by joining couple of tables in my database.I need to three column one count of projects,grouping attribute and 'attribute with count of project'  and I need the outcome of the query as
project ,%complete and Category as
2,0,c1-1c2-1
1,25,c3-1
1,50,c4-1
*Data set:*

Select a1.projectid,
a2.complete(%),
a3.categrory
from a1
join a2 on a1.id=a2.id
join a3 on a1.id=a3.id

when the outcome of the query is
Project %Complete   Categroy
A100    0   C1
A200    0   C2
A300    25  C3
A400    50  C4

Then I need to pull the count of project ,%complete and Category as
2,0,c1-1c2-1
1,25,c3-1
1,50,c4-1
Any suggestions how to achieve this.

Comment: This still needs a lot of editing to be understood, and you haven't show what you've tried, or how it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Example for reference in Oracle Assuming you are checking on the basis of %complete :

```
with table1 as 
(
select 'A100' as project ,0 as complete_percent, 'C1' as category from dual
union
select 'A200', 0,'C2' from dual
union
select 'A300', 25,'C3' from dual
union
select 'A400', 50,'C4' from dual
union
select 'A500', 0,'C5' from dual
union
select 'A600', 25,'C6' from dual
union
select 'A700', 50,'C7' from dual
union
select 'A800', 60,'c8' from dual
)
select distinct count_prj,complete_percent,listagg(str) within group  (order by NULL) over (partition by complete_percent) 
from (select count(*) over (partition by complete_percent) count_prj,complete_percent,
category || '-' || count(*) over (partition by category,complete_percent) str 
from table1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs

Comment: Pleasure is mine :)